# A tag for Brazilian TeXers (ABNT)

Tags: discussion, tagging

So, I am Brazilian and I've seen a few questions in TeX.SX regarding the two Brazilian Standards (ABNT - *Associação Brasileira de Normas Técnicas*, in English *Brazilian Association for Technical Standards*) related packages ([`abntex2`](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/doc/abntex2.pdf) and [`abntex2cite`](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/doc/abntex2cite.pdf)). So I took the curiosity to see if there was a tag for those and surprisingly enough there is: [abntcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abntcite). But as you can see it holds only 1 question (what a tag huh?), but don't give up on me just yet. If you search for `abntex` [you get 19 results](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=abntex), and for just `abnt` [50 results](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=abnt)! So,

#### The problem

The tag is a reference to a deprecated package, `abntcite` which gave its way to the former linked `abntex2cite`. And the poor `abntex2` class is left tagless.

---

#### My Proposition

We take [abntcite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abntcite) and make it just [abnt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abnt) which would be meant for all questions regarding documents with format following the ABNT Standards!

How about it?

Comment: I sustain the proposal. So I'll know when to keep at large from a question. `;-)`

Comment: `¬¬` Smarty pants...

Comment: I'm also Brazilian and fortunately never had to use abnTeX. But I believe that you will get more help from http://www.abntex.net.br/ instead of here on SE.

Comment: @Sigur, Initially I thought that too, but then looking the website I realized that there are several disadvantages of getting help from abntex.net.br and getting help from here. The most important: TeX.SX (1) offers way much more people, (2) has people with deep knowledge of other TeX things, therefore could spot other issues and (3) if they could dive into the TeX.SX (as you and I did) there'd be more chances of they sticking to the community and TeX itself (which may as well be the most important). Also is TeX.SX not supposed to be TeX help center? `:)`

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos, OK. I agree but it would take too much time to people here understand the abnt rules to help us. Some rules doesn't fit in the TeX scope, I mean, they ask some absurd norms so that could be 'offensive' to TeX... :-)

Comment: @Sigur, Yes that's right, ABNT is ulgy and TeX is beautiful, and make something ugly out of a beautiful tool is to some extent offensive. Though understanding ABNT is unecessary. Providing solutions to a (La)TeX knowledge deficiency is the main point, I think. Just as an ending argument: I see tons of questions asking how to format some document in a way that makes awful, still solutions are provided and advices on better formatting are also given. I hope you come around regarding the {abnt} `:D` perhaps one day it changes for the better!

Answer (score 15):

I've seized the initiative and created the [abnt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abnt) tag. I just assigned it to a question that clearly falls in the scope of the tag.

I leave to our Brazilian friends, so fond of their beloved ABNT, to retag other questions.

Comment: What of the [tag:abntcite]? it should be removed, I think.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Probably so

Comment: Fond of ABNT? You've got to be kidding me. We feel deep repugnance for it.

Comment: @eduardo.tex In Italian we have the idiom “chi disprezza compra”, which in Portuguese would be ”quem desdenha, quer comprar”. `;-)` Do you have a similar idiom?

Comment: @egreg: We do, but it's false. `:D`

Comment: We sure despise it and don't want to buy it, but are forced to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! This tag, {abnt}, should be useful.

But does this mean that other language-type-tags shall appear?

Time'll tell.

Comment: Maybe, yeah. But the point of the tag is not to cover the ABNT itself, is to cover the class and package from LaTeX, issues with those ones. If there are language-type packages and/or classes in CTAN that often need troubleshooting I'll also say yes to its tags! `:D`

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos I understand your point and agree as well! :P

Comment: Brazil is peculiar in that it has ABNT. The proposed tag should not be added to every question involving Brazilian Portuguese, but only to those that are connected with ABNT, for instance usage of `abntex2.cls` or how to comply with citations in ABNT style.